# find the difference between a negative and positive number

Tags: java

I have a value stored in my db.table as arrears which has a minus sign eg arrears = -100.0 and when an amount is to be paid to cancel or reduce the arrears, am getting wrong results. eg:
arrears = -100.0 is displayed in a jtextfiled named 'arrears' from db.table
user inputs amount to be paid into a textbox named 'pay'.
a calculation must be done and new arrears must be entered back into 'arrears' jtextfield.This is the code I wrote below:

```
double a,b,e;
a=Double.valueOf(arrears.getText());
b=Double.valueOf(pay.getText());
e=a+b;
arrears.setText(String.valueOf(e));
```

`arreas`= -100.0, `amount paid` = 50.0 after the calculation I get answer as `-45.0` instead of `-50`. please what is the problem.

Comment: use a debugger. check `a` and `b` values

Comment: sorry I just edited that part. its rather a+b.

Comment: I don't think any problem is there in above code, submit the surrounded code as well

Comment: bro am stil getting -45 instead of minus 50 @Ali786. on my calculator I get the right answer. I just cant tell why in the program its wrong

Comment: @jhamon, can u please give me a sample code on how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is look like problem isn't in a calculation. I recommend you using debugger or logging, for example:

```
double a,b,e;
System.out.println("arrears = " + arrears.getText());
System.out.println("pay =" + pay.getText());

a=Double.valueOf(arrears.getText());
b=Double.valueOf(pay.getText());
e=a+b;

System.out.println("a = " + a);
System.out.println("b = " + b);
System.out.println("e = " + e);

arrears.setText(String.valueOf(e));
```

Answer (score 1):

User enters 5 in pay text field—> 5 is added to arrears, user enters 0 into pay text field —> 50 is added and total value is now -100 + 5 + 50 = 45

Comment: @joakim_Danielson that means the input pay is calculated twice.one by 5 and then by 50 because of the sequence of the input which is 5, then 0. is there a way I can make it perform the action once. am using key released. its working with others perfectly but not the arrears type.

Comment: ok @ScaryWombat. how about the enter key. eg. action get performed when enter key is pressed. hope that will solve the problem

Comment: An action listener for when Enter is pressed in the text field sounds like a good solution.